# Extract Excel file names into Sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2013, workflow, excel

I have SharePoint online 2013 and workflow 2010.

I have a list of excel files that I'd like to extract the names into SharePoint List.

Is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean you have a local folder with bunch of excel documents and you want their names to be stored into a SharePoint online list? Recurring activity or one time job?

Comment: Yes. Mainly, to show the names of the files in a dropdown list in SP field.

Answer (score 0):

**SharePoint 2010 workflows have been retired** since August 1, 2020 for new tenants and removed from existing tenants on **November 1, 2020**. **It is recommended that you use MS Flow (Power Automate)**.

**Please follow steps:**

1. Upload Excel files to SharePoint Documents Library

[image]

2. Create a List named "**Excel List**" to store Excel file Title
3. Go back SharePoint Documents Library, click  **▪▪▪** >> **Automate** >> **Power Autonate** >> to create a flow

[image]

4. Workflow Steps:

- Add the "**When an item is created or modified**" Trigger
- Add the "**Get files (properties only)**" Action
- Add a **Condition**: **[Get files (properties only)] Title contains xlsx**
- on the "**If yes**" branch, add the "**Create item**" Action

[image]

5. **Save** and **Test** this flow. And go to the "**Excel List**" page, you will view page screen as shown in the figure below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I don't have MS Flow. Only InfoPath, SPD 2010 and SP2013. Is there another way? MS Flow has to be purchased right?

Comment: Hi, Madeline. Yes, the best way is to use MS Flow. You could click https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/microsoft-flow/9nkn0p5l9n84?activetab=pivot:overviewtab  to read more information.